# vertical alignment between axis and node tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment, axis

I would like to reproduce with tikz the figure at the bottom. I did the graph dependence plot and I would like to add a time series above like you can seen.

Thank you[image]

As you can see i need perfect alignement between circle (node) t_i  in the graph and the time t_i in the axis.

Bellow the tikz code for the graph dependency :

```
   \begin{tikzpicture}[main/.style={circle, minimum size = 10mm, thick, draw        =black!80, node distance = 10mm},
    box/.style={rectangle, draw=black!100}]
          % put nodes
      \node[main,draw =red!80] (t1) {$t_i$};
      \node[main] (t2) [right= 3cm of t1] {$t_{i+1}$};
      \node[main] (t3) [right= of t2] {$t_{i+2}$};
      \node[main] (tn) [right= of t3] {$t_{n}$};
      \node[main] (t)  [left= 3cm of t1] {$t_{i-1}$};
      \node[main] (tt) [left=  of t]  {$t_{i-2}$};
      \node[main] (t0) [left=  of tt] {$t_{0}$};

      % make path ...
      \path (t3) -- node[auto=false]{\ldots} (tn);
      \path (tt) -- node[auto=false]{\ldots} (t0);

      % draw arrows
      \draw [->,dashed] (t1) to [out=45,in=165] node [midway, above]       {$P(k=n|\lambda=1)$} (tn); 
      \draw [->,dashed] (t1) to [out=-10,in=-155] node [midway, below]{$P(k=i+2|\lambda=1)$}(t3);
      \draw [->,dashed] (t1) to  node [midway, above] {$P(k=i+1|\lambda=1)$}(t2);
      \draw [->,dashed] (t1) to  node [midway, above] {$P(k=i-1|\lambda=1)$} (t);
      \draw [->,dashed] (t1) to [out=-155,in=-20] node [midway, below]{$P(k=i-2|\lambda=1)$}(tt);
      \draw [->,dashed] (t1) to [out=135,in=15] node [midway, above]       {$P(k=0|\lambda=1)$}(t0);
   \end{tikzpicture}
```

**EDIT 1**
Example of time series

```
        \begin{tikzpicture} 
        \begin{axis}[name=p, legend pos=south west, grid =major,           symbolic x coords=                                        {$t_1$,$t_2$,$t_3$,$t_4$,$t_5$,$t_6$,$t_7$,$t_8$,$t_9$,$t_n$}] 

        \addplot+[smooth, color=blue] coordinates { 
                  ($t_1$,42) 
                  ($t_2$,43) 
                  ($t_3$,42) 
                  ($t_5$,41) 
                  ($t_7$,34.1) 
                  ($t_8$,40) 
                  ($t_9$,40.5) 
                  ($t_n$,41)}; 
      \end{axis}
      \end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: What kind of data is in that time series? Do you have for example a text file of data that you want to plot, or do you just need some qualitative graph?

Comment: no matter, I just want a quantitative time series with arbitrary values. Please look at my EDIT 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**: I also show temporarily what you are requesting.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\pgfplotsset{width=16cm,height=6cm,compat=1.15}
\begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[main/.style={circle, minimum size = 10mm, thick, draw        =black!80, node distance = 10mm},
    box/.style={rectangle, draw=black!100}] 
        \begin{axis}[name=p, legend pos=south west, grid =major,           
        symbolic x coords={$t_0$,$t_1$,$t_2$,$t_3$,$t_4$,$t_5$,$t_6$,$t_7$,$t_8$,$t_9$,$t_{10}$,$t_n$}] 

        \addplot+[smooth, color=blue] coordinates { 
                  ($t_0$,42) 
                  ($t_1$,43) 
                  ($t_2$,42) 
                  ($t_5$,41) 
                  ($t_8$,34.1) 
                  ($t_9$,40) 
%                  ($t_{11}$,40.5) 
                  ($t_n$,41)}; 
        \coordinate (T1) at (axis cs:{[normalized]-1},0);                 
        \coordinate (T2) at (axis cs:{[normalized]1},0);                  
        \coordinate (T3) at (axis cs:{[normalized]2},0);                  
        \coordinate (T5) at (axis cs:{[normalized]5},0);                  
        \coordinate (T8) at (axis cs:{[normalized]8},0);                  
        \coordinate (T9) at (axis cs:{[normalized]9},0);                  
        \coordinate (T10) at (axis cs:{[normalized]10},0);                
        \coordinate (T11) at (axis cs:{[normalized]11},0);                
      \end{axis}
      \node[main,draw =red!80] (t1) at (T5|- 0,-3){$t_i$};
      \node[main] (t2) at (T8|- 0,-3) {$t_{i+1}$};
      \node[main] (t3) at (T9|- 0,-3) {$t_{i+2}$};
      \node[main] (tn) at (T11|- 0,-3) {$t_{n}$};
      \node[main] (t) at (T3|- 0,-3) {$t_{i-1}$};
      \node[main] (tt) at (T2|- 0,-3)  {$t_{i-2}$};
      \node[main] (t0) at (T1|- 0,-3) {$t_{0}$};

      % make path ...
      \path (t3) -- node[auto=false]{\ldots} (tn);
      \path (tt) -- node[auto=false]{\ldots} (t0);

      % draw arrows
      \draw [->,dashed] (t1) to [out=45,in=165] node [midway, above]       {$P(k=n|\lambda=1)$} (tn); 
      \draw [->,dashed] (t1) to [out=-10,in=-155] node [midway, below]{$P(k=i+2|\lambda=1)$}(t3);
      \draw [->,dashed] (t1) to  node [midway, above] {$P(k=i+1|\lambda=1)$}(t2);
      \draw [->,dashed] (t1) to  node [midway, above] {$P(k=i-1|\lambda=1)$} (t);
      \draw [->,dashed] (t1) to [out=-155,in=-20] node [midway, below]{$P(k=i-2|\lambda=1)$}(tt);
      \draw [->,dashed] (t1) to [out=135,in=15] node [midway, above]       {$P(k=0|\lambda=1)$}(t0);
      \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

IMHO it is just not too beautiful.

**UPDATE**: An attempt to show your data. Note that at some point one needs to synchronize the width of the plot with your graph dependence plot, which uses fixed distances.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}[main/.style={circle, minimum size = 10mm, thick, draw        =black!80, node distance = 10mm},
    box/.style={rectangle, draw=black!100}]
          % put nodes
      \node[main,draw =red!80] (t1) {$t_i$};
      \node[main] (t2) [right= 3cm of t1] {$t_{i+1}$};
      \node[main] (t3) [right= of t2] {$t_{i+2}$};
      \node[main] (tn) [right= of t3] {$t_{n}$};
      \node[main] (t)  [left= 3cm of t1] {$t_{i-1}$};
      \node[main] (tt) [left=  of t]  {$t_{i-2}$};
      \node[main] (t0) [left=  of tt] {$t_{0}$};

      % make path ...
      \path (t3) -- node[auto=false]{\ldots} (tn);
      \path (tt) -- node[auto=false]{\ldots} (t0);

      % draw arrows
      \draw [->,dashed] (t1) to [out=45,in=165] node [midway, above]       {$P(k=n|\lambda=1)$} (tn); 
      \draw [->,dashed] (t1) to [out=-10,in=-155] node [midway, below]{$P(k=i+2|\lambda=1)$}(t3);
      \draw [->,dashed] (t1) to  node [midway, above] {$P(k=i+1|\lambda=1)$}(t2);
      \draw [->,dashed] (t1) to  node [midway, above] {$P(k=i-1|\lambda=1)$} (t);
      \draw [->,dashed] (t1) to [out=-155,in=-20] node [midway, below]{$P(k=i-2|\lambda=1)$}(tt);
      \draw [->,dashed] (t1) to [out=135,in=15] node [midway, above]       {$P(k=0|\lambda=1)$}(t0);
      \coordinate[above=2cm of t0] (O);
      \coordinate (F) at (O -|tn);
      \begin{scope}[shift=(O),yscale=3]
      \draw [thick,-latex] (O) -- ($(F)+(1,0)$) node[right]{$t$};
      \draw [thick,-latex] (O) -- ++(0,1.5);
      \draw[smooth,blue,thick] plot  coordinates {(0,1.1) (2,1.2) 
                  (4,1.3) 
                  (6,1.2) 
                  (8,1.1) 
                  (10,0.41) 
                  (12,1.0) 
                  (14,1.05) 
                  (16,1.1)}; 
      \foreach \X/\Y in {t1/{$t_i$},t2/{$t_{i+1}$},t3/{$t_{i+2}$},tn/{$t_{n}$},t/{$t_{i-1}$},tt/{$t_{i-2}$},t0/{$t_{0}$}}
       {\draw (O-|\X) -- ++(0,-1mm) node[below] {\Y};}
      \end{scope}
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And just fleshing out Torbjørn T.'s suggestion

```
 \draw[smooth,blue,thick] plot  coordinates {(t0|-0,1.1) (tt|-0,1.2) 
              (t|-0,1.3) 
              (t1|-0,1.2) 
              (t2|-0,0.41) 
              (t3|-0,1.1) 
              (tn|-0,1.0)};
```

yields

[image]

The question is if you want to you use pgfplots for this. You can, but then you need to use different methods for the mutual "synchronization".

**Original answer**:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\newcommand{\randomlist}[4]{% points, displacement,seed, y0
\xdef\y{#4}
\pgfmathsetseed{#3} 
\foreach \x [count=\n] in {0,...,#1}
{
    \pgfmathparse{\y + rand*#2} % computing next step of random walk
    \xdef\y{\pgfmathresult}
    \xdef\finaly{\pgfmathresult}
    \xdef\finaln{\n}
    \ifnum\n=1\relax
    \xdef\lst{(\x,\y)}
    \else
    \global\xdef\lst{\lst\space (\x,\y)}
    \fi
}
}

\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}[main/.style={circle, minimum size = 10mm, thick, draw        =black!80, node distance = 10mm},
    box/.style={rectangle, draw=black!100}]
          % put nodes
      \node[main,draw =red!80] (t1) {$t_i$};
      \node[main] (t2) [right= 3cm of t1] {$t_{i+1}$};
      \node[main] (t3) [right= of t2] {$t_{i+2}$};
      \node[main] (tn) [right= of t3] {$t_{n}$};
      \node[main] (t)  [left= 3cm of t1] {$t_{i-1}$};
      \node[main] (tt) [left=  of t]  {$t_{i-2}$};
      \node[main] (t0) [left=  of tt] {$t_{0}$};

      % make path ...
      \path (t3) -- node[auto=false]{\ldots} (tn);
      \path (tt) -- node[auto=false]{\ldots} (t0);

      % draw arrows
      \draw [->,dashed] (t1) to [out=45,in=165] node [midway, above]       {$P(k=n|\lambda=1)$} (tn); 
      \draw [->,dashed] (t1) to [out=-10,in=-155] node [midway, below]{$P(k=i+2|\lambda=1)$}(t3);
      \draw [->,dashed] (t1) to  node [midway, above] {$P(k=i+1|\lambda=1)$}(t2);
      \draw [->,dashed] (t1) to  node [midway, above] {$P(k=i-1|\lambda=1)$} (t);
      \draw [->,dashed] (t1) to [out=-155,in=-20] node [midway, below]{$P(k=i-2|\lambda=1)$}(tt);
      \draw [->,dashed] (t1) to [out=135,in=15] node [midway, above]       {$P(k=0|\lambda=1)$}(t0);
      \coordinate[above=2cm of t0] (O);
      \coordinate (F) at (O -|tn);
      \begin{scope}[shift=(O)]
      \draw [thick,-latex] (O) -- ($(F)+(1,0)$) node[right]{$t$};
      \draw [thick,-latex] (O) -- ++(0,4);
      \randomlist{16}{0.4}{7}{1.4}% play with these parameters to get another curve
      \draw[smooth,blue,thick] plot coordinates {\lst};
      \foreach \X/\Y in {t1/{$t_i$},t2/{$t_{i+1}$},t3/{$t_{i+2}$},tn/{$t_{n}$},t/{$t_{i-1}$},tt/{$t_{i-2}$},t0/{$t_{0}$}}
       {\draw (O-|\X) -- ++(0,-1mm) node[below] {\Y};}
      \end{scope}
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, in fact i need simply an arbitrary time series like  i showed in my Edit 1.  can your solution be used in my case? Thanks agian

Comment: You could even use coordinates like `(t0|-0,1.1)` in the `plot coordinates`, to avoid the fixed x-values.

Comment: it works very well thank you. however, I would like to know how to use my plot (axis with the grid) and not the coordinates as you did. Is there a way to synchronize my graph dependence plot  and my axis plot (with grid) that I put in the edit?.

Comment: @FiesAtoS I added something along the lines you were suggesting.